# What is the translation of the exchange between John Wick and Ares?

Tags: translation, john-wick-chapter-2

In John Wick: Chapter 2, around 66 minutes into the film, John Wick and Ares have an (untranslated) interaction.
Wick and Cassian enter the Continental hotel in Rome, and have a drink. Cassian leaves, and John turns to Ares, who sat behind the two. Here they communicate using sign language. Ares seems very annoyed with John's reply.

**What is the exact translation of this interaction?**

And a subordinate question:
Throughout the film there are a few more conversations between the two - when they first meet, when Ares confronts Wick in the catacombs, and during their last scene together in the museum: do these interactions have significant consequences for the interpretation of that conversation, or Wick's or the audience's relationship with her? If so, what are their translations?

Comment: Related, partial answer: [Does Ares expect her wound not to prove fatal after the 'mirrors' fight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92386/does-ares-expect-her-wound-not-to-prove-fatal-after-the-mirrors-fight) And apparently - according to the answer there - there should be translations of their interactions, but the version I saw on Netflix didn't show them, nor did it have English translations, so I expected them to be 'unknown', like the Russian and Italian dialogue. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

Odd...my copy has their translations **on screen** in English.

An ASL user explains/reviews here as to the *quality* of the usage which includes the bar scene clip...

ASL translation only of bar scene.

> Ares: Having a tough night?

> Area: Can I buy you a drink?

> Ares: Not him... ME.

> Ares: Be seeing you John Wick.

> John Wick: Not if I see you FIRST.

Comment: Weird how the "not him ..me" is not being addressed in the video. What does that imply? Who is the implied "him", Cassian?

Comment: Yes Cassian....